# Ruby regex not validating in condition?

Tags: ruby, regex, if-statement

I wrote my first regex and an `if` condition to check a passed `def` argument loop.
It doesn't seem to be working properly, and I am guessing I have something wrong with the regex.  The condition runs, but it says the value doesn't match the regex when it does match the pattern I want, and vice-versa.

The pattern I need is like this: `123456_12345_ABC_123`:

```
6 digits 
underscore
5 digits (may include 0 padding)
underscore
3 upper case letters
underscore
3 digits (may include 0 padding)
```

Here is my code:

```
if ev_val.match(/[0-9]{6}(_)[0-9]{5}(_)[a-z]{3}(_)[0-9]{3}/)

    puts "#{ev_val} matches required batch naming convention"
else
    puts "#{ev_val} doesn't match required batch naming convention\nSTOPPING SCRIPT!!!"
    exit
end
```

If anyone has any thoughts, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
/[0-9]{6}(_)[0-9]{5}(_)[a-z]{3}(_)[0-9]{3}/
```

You can use:

```
/\d{6}_\d{5}_[A-Z]{3}_\d{3}/
```

- `\d` is a digit, AKA `[0-9]`, so you should get used to using that short-hand.
- `(_)` doesn't accomplish anything in your code, so don't capture the underscore, instead simply use `_`.
- `[a-z]` captures all *lower*-case letters. You want upper-case so use `[A-Z]`.

Comment: Good but you should add `0*`'s where he says `may include 0 padding` (unless I'm reading that wrong.)

Comment: Thank you for both of your responses! I had the \d first, but I had read it was exactly 1 digit, so that I thought that was why it wasn't working.  I had also read parentheses looks for a literal character, which is why I put the underscore in them.  Looks like I have much to learn for regex!  I've been avoiding it, but I know that learning it will give me a great advantage in coding.

Yes, any of the digits are 0 padded (all the way up to the first digit).  I will try to look that up. but if someone knows the shorthand, I am much obliged.

Comment: Never mind.  I figured it out! /0*\d{6}_0*\d{5}_[A-Z]{3}_0*\d{3}/  Thanks!

Comment: Just as a side note. This does find the string, even if there are characters on the end.  It passed every test except 123456_12345_ABC_123zz  That shouldn't pass, because of the zz, but it does.  This is in a csv with double quotes around it.  By the time the script is evaluating it, the double quotes are stripped, but I don't know why it allows the extra characters on the end.